# FFMPEG, convert video same as input size with watermark in Batch

Tags: batch-file, video, ffmpeg

I would like to watermark some videos in a directory. I use a png watermark of 3840x2160 in size. The watermark should go in fullsize on the video. Because my videos have different resolutions I use this batch script

```bash
set /p add_watermark=Wasserzeichen Addieren? (Standard: ja/nein):
if /i "%add_watermark%" == "" set add_watermark=ja

if /i "%add_watermark%" == "ja" (
    for %%f in (%cd%\output\tmp\*.mp4) do (
        set "filename=%%~nf"
        ffmpeg -i "%%f" -i %cd%\watermark\watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih[v0][v1];[v0][v1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-0:0" -c:a copy -map 0 -y "%cd%\output\%%~nf.mp4"
    )
)
```

That works well with videos in 4k but if my input is a HD video it will scale the output up to 4k in the size of the watermark.

If I try to add
`-c:v copy` FFMPEG is giving out the error

```
Streamcopy requested for output stream fed from a complex filtergraph. Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.
```

My question is, how can I set the output as same size as the input video with the scaled watermark without doing this in two steps.

Comment: I would first of all advise replacing line 1 with ```%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /M "Wasserzeichen Addieren"```, replacing line 2 with ```If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo :EOF```, removing ```%cd%\``` from lines 5 and 7, then erasing both line 4, and line 9.

Comment: Good Point! My code is now a bit cleaner. I had some issues with finding the correct directory but it also works without %cd%\. But when i replace the first line,- i also loose my ability to hit just enter.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window type `choice /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key. You should note that there's a `/d`efault option, which can be used with a `/t`imer. This means that flow could continue if you press nothing. As it currently stands, you've got code which will accept the press of any one, or a series of keystrokes. Some of those can be potentially very dangerous, even if just pressed accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

Because it seems there is no other idea how to archive this in on step without re-encoding i did a  batch script that extracts the resolution from the video files and use it to change the link to a watermark.png in different resolutions.

As example:

```
watermark_1920x1080.png
watermark_2560x1440.png
watermark_3840x2160.png
```

and so on. This is only a impractical workaround (but well it works) i let this question open.